# Linear Algebra Vectorspace $V=\operatorname{Fun}(X,F)$

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider the vector space $V=\operatorname{Fun}(X,F)$ where $F$ is a field. Where $\operatorname{Fun}(X,F)$ is the set of all functions $X\to F$. How do you show that there is a zero element in $V$? And how would you describe the additive inverse?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/968049/fields-sets-and-vector-spaces

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the additive operation on $V$ is the [pointwise addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise), defined by $(f\mathbf{+}g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for $f,g\in V$ and $x \in X$. The zero in V is the function that maps every element of $X$ to zero. The additive inverse of a function $f$ is the function that maps $x\mapsto -f(x)$.

UPDATE

To show this we first show how the zero function works. Let call it $z$, defined by $z(x)=0 \ \forall x\in X $. What is $f\mathbf{+}z$? We have to look at the pointwise action of this sum so $$(f\mathbf{+}z)(x)\stackrel{\mbox{def}}{=}f(x)+z(x)=f(x)+0=f(x)$$ so we have proven $f\mathbf{+}z = f$. Now for the additive inverse: given $f$ we define its inverse $\bar{f}$ by $\bar{f}(x)=-f(x)$. Now we will show that $f+\bar{f}=z$. Indeed: $$(f\mathbf{+}\bar{f})(x)\stackrel{\mbox{def}}{=}f(x)+\bar{f}(x)=f(x)+(-f(x))=0=z(x)$$

Comment: How do i go about showing this?

Comment: I updated the answer.