# Fields, sets and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

How do I show this? I am new to all concepts in this question, however I am aware of the definitions of all concepts given.

Answer (score 1):

You have a definition of vector space. It is a set (in the problem, $V$ is this set), and a pair of operations.

1. Figure out what operations are these, and how they are defined. It is easy, don't bother with bizarre operations.
2. Prove that these operations satisfy all the properties that are required in the vector space definition. (This completes the first question).
3. Name the elements of the set $S$, for example $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Try to find a base for $V$. $1$'s and $0$'s can be very handy. Prove that this is indeed a base.
4. How many elements has this base? This is the dimension of $V$. And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $W$ be the set of functions from $S$ to $K$.

First you need to define addition and scalar multiplication on $W$.  If $f$ and $g$ are functions from $S$ to $K$ we define $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and for $\lambda$ in $K$ we define $(\lambda f)(x)=\lambda(f(x))$.  Now you must check that the axioms of a vector space are satisfied.

For the second part, let $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ and show that a basis of $W$ is given by the functions $f_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ where $f_i(s_j)$ equals $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.